# Validate object with condition in array with Joi

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi, hapi

I'm working on the following code in which I have to perform some validation using the Joi library.

The validation explanation is the following: when `type` is equal `ABC` and in the array `arrayOfObjects` there's a `objectInArray.id` equals to a specific value in a range of allowed values (in this case, the UUID `'012345ab-c678-910d-e111-f21g3h14i15j'`) and also when there's the object `anotherObjectInArray` not null, then `objectToValidate` should exist with the required attributes `field1` and `field2`, otherwise `objectToValidate` is optional.

```
const data = {
    type: "ABC",
    arrayOfObjects: [
        {
            objectInArray: {
                id: '012345ab-c678-910d-e111-f21g3h14i15j',
                value: "test"
            },
            anotherObjectInArray: {
                some_field: "some_value"
            },
            otherData: "...",
        },
        {
            objectInArray: {
                id: '161718kl-m192-021n-o222-p32q4r25s26t',
                value: "test2"
            },
            otherData: "..."
        }
    ],
    objectToValidate: {
        field1: "value",
        field2: true
    }
}
```

I tried to do the following validation but it failed.

```
objectToValidate: Joi.when('type', {
    is: 'ABC',
    then: Joi.when('arrayOfObjects', {
        is: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
            objectInArray: Joi.object({
                id: Joi.string().guid().required().valid('012345ab-c678-910d-e111-f21g3h14i15j', 'other_uuid')
            }).required()
        }).required()),
        then: Joi.when('arrayOfObjects', {
            is: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
                anotherObjectInArray: Joi.object().not(null)
            })),
            then: Joi.object({
                field1: Joi.string().required(),
                field2: Joi.boolean().strict().required()
            }).required(),
            otherwise: Joi.object().optional()
        }),
        otherwise: Joi.object().optional()
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.object().optional()
})
```

Can anyone point what's wrong with my code, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to play around with [.when](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options) and [.has](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayhasschema).

This schema is just a sample, you might need to make a few adjustments:

```
Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string(),
  arrayOfObjects:Joi.array(),
  objectToValidate: Joi.object()
}).when(Joi.object({ 
  type: Joi.valid('ABC'),
  arrayOfObjects: Joi.array().items().has(Joi.object({ 
      objectInArray: Joi.object({ id: Joi.valid('012345ab-c678-910d-e111-f21g3h14i15j'), value: Joi.valid() }),
      anotherObjectInArray: Joi.not(null)
    }).unknown()),
}).unknown(), {
  then: Joi.object({
    objectToValidate: Joi.required()
  }),
})
```

With `.has` we are saying that must exist at least one with those conditions, which means this example will fail because there is at least one object with `objectInArray.id = 012345ab-c678-910d-e111-f21g3h14i15j` and `anotherObjectInArray` not null, so `objectToValidate` will be required:

```
{
  type: "ABC",
  arrayOfObjects: [
    {
      objectInArray: {
        id: 'abcd',
        value: "test"
      },
      anotherObjectInArray: null
    },
      {
      objectInArray: {
        id: '012345ab-c678-910d-e111-f21g3h14i15j',
        value: "test"
      },
      anotherObjectInArray: { }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the error:

> Validation Error: "objectToValidate" is required

And this object will pass:

```
{
  type: "ABC",
  arrayOfObjects: [
    {
      objectInArray: {
        id: 'abcd',
        value: "test"
      },
      anotherObjectInArray: null
    },
      {
      objectInArray: {
        id: '12313',
        value: "test"
      },
      anotherObjectInArray: null
    }
  ]
}
```

Because we don't have the required fields, which means `objectToValidate` won't be required.

And, you don't need to use Joi.optional() many times, that's the default.